# Retrieving the original coordinates of a pixel taken from a warped Image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, distortion, 3d-reconstruction, perspectivecamera

I have four corners extracted from a *sourceImage*:

```
src_vertices[0] = corners[upperLeft];
src_vertices[1] = corners[upperRight];   
src_vertices[2] = corners[downLeft];
src_vertices[3] = corners[downRight];
```

These four corners are warped to *destinationImage* like that:

```
dst_vertices[0] = Point(0,0);
dst_vertices[1] = Point(width, 0); 
dst_vertices[2] = Point(0, height);
dst_vertices[3] = Point(width, height);

Mat warpPerspectiveMatrix = getPerspectiveTransform(src_vertices, dst_vertices);
cv::Size size_d =  Size(width, height);
cv::Mat DestinationImage(width,height,CV_8UC3);
warpPerspective(sourceImage, destinationImage, warpPerspectiveMatrix, size_d, INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);
```

Now my question is:

I have a point p(x,y) taken from the *destinationImage* how can I retrieve the coordinates of this point in the original sourceImage

In other words I want to use warpPerspectiveMatrix to do the opposite work of getPerspectiveTransform

Comment: If you obtain a new `warpPerspectiveMatrix` by now mapping from the destination to the source, and then apply it to a single point, you would get what you are after. What is the problem in doing that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the inverse perspective transform. If your original transform is S->S', you want the transform matrix S'->S

```
Mat InversewarpPerspectiveMatrix = getPerspectiveTransform(dst_vertices, src_vertices);
```

Then you make a SPARSE matrix

```
Mat PerspectiveCoordinates containing the vector x,y.
```

Finally you want to call

```
PerspectiveTransform(PerspectiveCoordinates,OriginalCoordinates,InversewarpPerspectiveMatrix)
```

Comment: What do you mean by SPARSE matrix!? how do I add the vector x,y to PerspectiveCoordinates!?

Comment: This is a whole another question.

Comment: Thank you Boyko, now all is fine

Comment: I'm not sure how to add them - I use the C functionality of OpenCV. I guess you've figured it out, glad to be of help!

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov or ZaherJoukhada any idea how to get the parse matrix using opencv I'm having the  same problem thanks!

Comment: @Engine try http://www.micc.unifi.it/ballan/downloads/ocv_tutorial.pdf page 23 "sets and sparse matrices"

Comment: Hi, I know its an old comment, but the link seems to be broken, can you please provide an alternate explanation of the sparse matrix part? also, at the final step, by using 'PerspectiveTransform' do you mean warpPerspective()? thank you very much!