# Retrieve original coordinates of a pixel from a warped image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, perspectivecamera

I was trying to follow along with [four-point-transform](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/) blog post with slight modifications using Python-3.6.
First I obtained four_point_transform of the given image. After getting the **warped** image, I plotted bounding box around text "*Hello*" using cv2.rectangle.

```
cv2.rectangle(warped, (37, 20), (222, 97), (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

Now, I want to plot the bounding box of text "Hello" in warped image on the original image. I referred to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343420/retrieving-the-original-coordinates-of-a-pixel-taken-from-a-warped-image/14346147). But I do not have the coordinates on the source image so could not follow along. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: if the image was warped with transformation matrix M, transform your pixel coordinates with M^-1 (inverse) to get pixel coordinates of the unwarped image.

Comment: @Micka, I actually want to know the original coordinates of  (37, 20) and (222, 97) on the original image and later use those values alone for further processing.

Comment: compute inverse-M * (37,20,1) and divide the result by its z coordinate to get the original point and same for the other point. Read about homography transformations in 2D space.